# [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of '(0 , _compositionApi.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined."

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, store, vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils

I am setting up tests on a `Nuxt2` app using `@nuxtjs/composition-api` and
`@vue/test-utils`.

In addition, there is a `vue-CLI` UI library using @`vue/composition-api` and `vue-demi`.

The issue is that even if the `context` is mocked as per solution [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/issues/248), our store is still `undefined` and the tests are failling.

`///// SET UP /////`

The `Nuxt2` app is set as follow:

`Package.json`

```
 "dependencies": {
   "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.20.2",
   "core-js": "2",
 }

 "devDependencies": {
   "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
   "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
   "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
   "jest": "^28.1.0",
   "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.0",
   "jest-junit": "^14.0.0",
   "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
 }
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
 alias: {
    'vue-demi': '@nuxtjs/composition-api',
  },
```

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
    '^.+\\.(s?css|less)$': '<rootDir>/css_stub.js',
    '^@atoms/(.*)$':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/UILIBRARY-path/$1',
    '^@molecules/(.*)$':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/UILIBRARY-path/$1',
    '^@organisms/(.*)$':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/UILIBRARY-path/$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/UILIBRARY'],
  moduleDirectories: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  globals: {
    'vue-jest': {
      babelConfig: {
        configFile: './babel.config.js',
      },
    },
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/vueSetup.js'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['components/**.vue', 'pages/**.vue'],
  coverageDirectory: 'tmp/coverage',
  reporters: ['default', ['jest-junit', { outputDirectory: 'tmp/coverage' }]],
  coverageReporters: ['text', 'html', 'cobertura'],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 0,
      branches: 0,
      functions: 0,
      lines: 0,
    },
  },
}
```

`test/vueSetp.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import VueFormulate from 'UILIBRARY/vue-formulate/src/Formulate'
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'

Vue.use(Buefy)
Vue.use(VueFormulate)

config.mocks.$t = (key) => key
config.mocks.$tc = (key) => key
```

`///// Component and Test ////`

`Component.vue`

```
export default {
  name: 'Component',
  setup() {
    const {
      store,
    } = useContext()

// when consol.log(store), it is defined

    const gettingStoreData = computed(
      () =>
        store.getters['data']?.key === 1
    )
```

`test.spec.js`

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '@/path-to-component/Component.vue'

jest.mock('@nuxtjs/composition-api')

describe('Component.vue', () => {
  const factory = (mockDataForm) => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component, {
      propsData: {
        various data
      },
      mocks: {
        $nuxt: {
          context: {
            store: {},
          },
        },

      },
      provide: {
        form: mockDataForm
      },
    })

    return wrapper
  }

  test('component mounts properly', () => {
    const wrapper = factory({
      various data
    })

    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
  })
```

There were a couple of attempts to define/ mock the store globally:

`vueSetup.js`

- setting a mock store globaly

```
config.mocks.store
```

- adding `$nuxt` to `Vue.prototype`

```
Vue.prototype.$nuxt = {
 context: {
   store: {},
 },
}
```

- creating a new Vue and adding store to its prototype

```
const newVue = new Vue({})

 newVue.prototype = (key) => key
  {
   context: {
     store: { $auth: {} },
```

But all of it result in the same error as in the title:

```
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of '(0 , _compositionApi.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

So what else could be done in order to not have an `undefined` store and be able to run the tests properly?

- Should Vuex be added (which sounds not good as it is a nuxt app)
- Is it actually only related to the store and not the context since mocking `$t` and `$tc` works fine?
- Could it be linked to the component code itself and not the test?

Many thanks in advance for your support and please let me know if there is any missing information or if you need more details.

Cheers,